# SailsJS Policy based route with a view

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to use the `routes.js` to define a route to `'/account'`.

I want whoever is trying to access that path to go through the `UserController` and the `checkLogin` action and if the security check passes, then the user should be rendered with the defined view which is `home/account`

Here is my code:

routes.js:

```
'/account': {
    controller: 'UserController',
    action: 'checkLogin',
    view: 'home/account'
  }
```

policies.js:

```
UserController: {
    '*': 'isAuthenticated',
    'login': true,
    'checkLogin': true
  }
```

It let's me view `/account` without going through the `isAuthenticated` policy check for some reason.

Comment: Quick question: it seems you're trying to put policy logic in the controller (from the sound of the name "checkLogin" is exactly what should be done in the isAuthenticated policy), have you modified that policy?

Answer (score 10):

There looks to be a little confusion here as to how policies, controllers and views work.  As @bredikhin notes above, your controller will never be called because the route is being bound to a view.  It's also important to note that policies cannot be bound to views, *only* to controllers.  The correct setup should be something like:

In `config/routes.js`:

```
'/account': 'UserController.account'
```

In `config/policies.js`:

```
UserController: {
  '*': 'isAuthenticated' // will run on all UserController actions
  // or
  'account': 'isAuthenticated' // will run just on account action
}
```

In `api/policies/isAuthenticated.js`:

```
    module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

     // Your auth code here, returning next() if auth passes, otherwise
     // res.forbidden(), or throw error, or redirect, etc.

    }
```

In `api/controllers/UserController.js`:

```
module.exports = {

  account: function(req, res) {

     res.view('home/account');

  }
}
```

Comment: this 'your controller will never be called because the route is being bound to a view' is a very important part of this answer

Answer (score 5):

To put it short: either controller/action-style or view-style routing should be used within the same route in `routes.js`, not both simultaneously.

According to the router's [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/1f9b4d5782b71178383e2e0420d37ddea81447ee/lib/router/bind.js#L51), once there is a `view` property in a route object, binding stops, so basically Sails never knows to which controller your `/account` path should be routed, which means that your `UserController`-specific policy config never fires.

So, just remove the `view` property from the route, you can always specify the view path (if you want a non-standard one) with explicit rendering from within your action.

Answer (score 1):

For statics work with policies, you can set your route with controller and action:

```
'GET /login': 'AuthController.index',
```

And set view/layout in your controller:

```
index: function (req, res) {
    res.view('auth/login', { layout: 'path/layout' } );
},
```